# Having errors when I want to read a zip file stored in blobstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This is my html page:

upload your file here:

```
 <form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/bootstrap") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="file" name="myFile">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

  </form>
```

This is my controller:

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 throws ServletException, IOException, UploadException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(request);
        BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("myFile");

        if (blobKey == null) {
        response.sendRedirect("/");
        } else {
            BlobKey blobKey2 = new BlobKey(blobKey.getKeyString());
            BlobstoreInputStream in = new BlobstoreInputStream(blobKey2);

            ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(in));
            ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();

            while (entry !=null){
                String fileName = entry.getName();
                int fileSize = (int) entry.getSize();

            }
        }
```

I am uploading a file that contains 6 zip files. I am able to upload it but i am not able to read the zip file. Any better solution or must i configure something?

Comment: What do you expect and what is the actual bahaviour (the error/problem)? *not able to read* is a bit vague..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to know the difference between Blob and BlobKey. It is possible to retrieve data stored in the blobstore that is more than 1MB by using BlobKey. The code below is a sample for reading a zipfile.

The API helped me to solve:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/

```
BlobstoreInputStream in = new BlobstoreInputStream(blobKey);
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(in));
ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();
```

Comment: You aren't listening. If any SINGLE FILE in the zip archive is larger than 1MB then that won't work. I've talked to app engine developers about this exact problem. The archive itself can be huge, that's fine, and you can READ it from the blobstore. But you cannot EXTRACT it if any single file is larger than 1MB. I don't know how I can be any clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If any single file in the zip archive that you are trying to extract is larger than 1MB it won't work. There is NO way around this. You can store whatever you want in blobstore, but GAE imposes a 1MB limit on any in-memory data structure; that means that if you are trying to operate on any object that is larger than 1MB your operation will fail. In your example above, your `ZipEntry` object is larger than 1MB if any file in your archive is larger than 1MB uncompressed.

Comment: I must not have been clear. If you are breaking the 1MB limit, then there is no solution. You can't use the App Engine. There is absolutely no way to extract a zip file on the App Engine if any single file in the archive is larger than 1MB, and there is absolutely no way around this. If you try to find a way around it, you will only be met with frustration, since it is impossible. Sorry.